# how to get an object literal properties with ts-morph

Tags: typescript, ts-morph

I am parsing a file like this using ts-morph

```js
const a = {property1: 20, property2: 30}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get an ObjectLiteralExpression mentioned here

https://ts-morph.com/details/object-literal-expressions

```js
const properties = objectLiteralExpression.getProperties();
// or
const property = objectLiteralExpression.getProperty("propertyAssignment");
// or
const spreadAssignment = objectLiteralExpression.getProperty(
    p => p.getText() === "...spreadAssignment",
);
// or
const method = objectLiteralExpression.getPropertyOrThrow("method");
```

This is what I am using so far. I am getting the initializer which returns an expression, but I can't find a way to get the object literal expression

```
    const project = new Project()
    project.addSourceFileAtPath(filePath)
    const sourceFile = project.getSourceFileOrThrow(filePath)
    const dec = sourceFile.getVariableDeclarationOrThrow(
      'a'
    )
    const objectLiteralExpression = dec.getInitializer() as ObjectLiteralExpression //
    console.log(objectLiteralExpression.getProperties())//This returns blank
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is the right way to do it. I named the variable wrong and it didn't throw

```js
const project = new Project()
    project.addSourceFileAtPath(filePath)
    const sourceFile = project.getSourceFileOrThrow(filePath)
    const dec = sourceFile.getVariableDeclarationOrThrow(
      'a'
    )
    const objectLiteralExpression = dec.getInitializer() as ObjectLiteralExpression //
    console.log(objectLiteralExpression.getProperties())//This returns blank
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by giving `ObjectLiteralExpression` to the initializer, like this:

```
const project = new Project()
project.addSourceFileAtPath(filePath)
const sourceFile = project.getSourceFileOrThrow(filePath)
const dec = sourceFile.getVariableDeclarationOrThrow(
    'a'
)
const dev = template.getVariableDeclarationOrThrow('a')
const objectLiteralExpression = dec.getInitializerIfKindOrThrow(ObjectLiteralExpression)
console.log(objectLiteralExpression.getProperties()) // output here
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me like this:

```
getInitializerIfKindOrThrow() accepts emum SyntaxKind

const project = new Project();
project.addSourceFileAtPath(filePath);
const sourceFile = project.getSourceFileOrThrow(filePath);
const dec = sourceFile.getVariableDeclarationOrThrow(
   'a'
);

const objectLiteralExpression = dec.getInitializerIfKindOrThrow(ts.SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression);
console.log(objectLiteralExpression.getProperties()); // output here
```